# Solr Multiple nodes in the same machine - good or bad idea?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Would it be a good idea to deploy multiple solr nodes into the same machine?
will search performance decrease or increase?

for example:
if I have 20GB ram machine, it is better to start two nodes of 8GB or only one of 16GB? what are the benefits?

I'm wondering, because is easy to do that, but I'm not sure if is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The question is far too broad (i.e. it's impossible to say if any of your options are better without knowing how, what and why you're querying data), but there are at least one advantage of running multiple processes:

- Multicore CPU usage. Usually a searcher (for a single query) runs on a single core. Running multiple instances on a single server allows multiple cores to be used (one pr. instance if I remember correctly) to build the result before merging.

The con would be that all caches are separate pr. process, and that you'll have more overhead and more complicated queries to keep everything running (i.e. most questions can't be answered from a single node), and you'll lose out on functionality that can't be distributed properly (although those are rare, it'll still affect certain functions).